# JavaFx & TornadoFX changing margin in CSS or TypeSafeCSS

Tags: css, javafx, tornadofx

Can i set hbox constraints(margins)in TypeSafeCss in TornadoFx or Css for JavaFx?

```
hbox {
  textfield {
    hboxConstraints {
      margin = Insets(5.0)
    }
  }
}
```

How to do this with CSS or TypeSafeCSS **without using padding**.

*As of the information of now thx to @fabian this is not possible in JavaFx*

Comment: In JavaFX CSS it' not possible to set `static` properties. (Someone else needs to tell you about TypeSafeCSS, since I'm not familiar with that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible so far.

Because TornadoFx depends on JavaFx
If JavaFx cant do it also TornadoFx cant.

Yes it might be possible with TornadoFx with a lot of tricks and tweaks but i/you would have to touch the JavaFx source code.